# Show Data to dropdownlist - "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to show the data to drop down list
I wrote this code

```
var Showtime = from _showtime in db.tbl_Concert_Showtime
               join _concerthall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _showtime.ConcertHallID equals _concerthall.ConcertHallID
               join _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context on _concerthall.ContextID equals _concert.ContextID
               where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
               select new
               {
                   ShowTimeID = _showtime.ShowtimeID,
                   Showtime = _showtime.StartDate.ToString() + " - ساعت " + _showtime.StartTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5) + "  الی    " + _showtime.EndTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5)
               };

ViewBag.ShowtimeID = new SelectList(Showtime, "ShowTimeID", "Showtime");
```

but I got this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Please help me to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is trying to convert your query to SQL, including the date formatting, and it doesn't know how to do that. Ususally the simplest way to fix this is to select the date as-is in SQL, and then do the formatting in LINQ to Objects. This can be acheived by called `.ToList()` before the formatting, which will force the execution of the SQL query at this point.

```
var showtimes =
    from _showtime ...
    from _showtime in db.tbl_Concert_Showtime
    join _concerthall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _showtime.ConcertHallID equals _concerthall.ConcertHallID
    join _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context on _concerthall.ContextID equals _concert.ContextID
    where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
    select new
    {
        ShowTimeID = _showtime.ShowtimeID,
        StartDate = _showtime.StartDate,
        StartTime = _showTime.StartTime,
        EndTime = _showtime.EndTime
    };

var formatted =
    from _showtime in showtimes.ToList()
    select new
    {
        ShowTimeID = _showtime.ShowtimeID,
        Showtime = _showtime.StartDate.ToString() + " - ???? " + _showtime.StartTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5) + "  ???    " + _showtime.EndTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5)
   };

ViewBag.ShowtimeID = new SelectList(formatted, "ShowTimeID", "Showtime");
```